# How to add a method after certain methods have been called

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, web-services, mkmapview

I have an app in which I use a google API to find places near a user. If they tap a cell named "ATM" on my table view, they are directed to a MapView which will display their user location on the map. They then have to press ANOTHER button called "show" on the screen to plot the points on the nearest ATM's. I want my app to run so that they don't have to press the second button, and once the map loads their user location, the app searches for the nearest "xyz's" near them. Here is the code for my querySearch:

```
-(void) queryGooglePlaces: (NSString *) googleType
{
    NSString *url = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/search/json?location=%f,%f&radius=%@&types=%@&sensor=true&key=%@", currentCentre.latitude, currentCentre.longitude, [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", currenDist], googleType, kGOOGLE_API_KEY];

    //Formulate the string as URL object.
    NSURL *googleRequestURL=[NSURL URLWithString:url];

    // Retrieve the results of the URL.
    dispatch_async(kBgQueue, ^{
        NSData* data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL: googleRequestURL];
        [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(fetchedData:) withObject:data waitUntilDone:YES];
    });
}
```

Here is the method I want to eliminate. I want this code to run once the map has focused on the user's location:

```
- (IBAction)showPlace:(id)sender {
    NSString *lowerString = [tappedString lowercaseString];
    [self queryGooglePlaces:lowerString];
}
```

And lastly, here are my MapView delegate method's incase they help:

```
- (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mv didAddAnnotationViews:(NSArray *)views
{

    //Zoom back to the user location after adding a new set of annotations.

    //Get the center point of the visible map.
    CLLocationCoordinate2D centre = [mv centerCoordinate];

    MKCoordinateRegion region;

    //If this is the first launch of the app then set the center point of the map to the user's location.
    if (firstLaunch) {
        region = MKCoordinateRegionMakeWithDistance(locationManager.location.coordinate,1000,1000);
        firstLaunch=NO;
    }else {
        //Set the center point to the visible region of the map and change the radius to match the search radius passed to the Google query string.
        region = MKCoordinateRegionMakeWithDistance(centre,currenDist,currenDist);
    }

    //Set the visible region of the map.
    [mv setRegion:region animated:YES];
}

- (MKAnnotationView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView viewForAnnotation:(id     <MKAnnotation>)annotation {

    //Define our reuse indentifier.
    static NSString *identifier = @"MapPoint";


    if ([annotation isKindOfClass:[MapPoint class]]) {

        MKPinAnnotationView *annotationView = (MKPinAnnotationView *) [self.mapView dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier:identifier];
        if (annotationView == nil) {
            annotationView = [[MKPinAnnotationView alloc] initWithAnnotation:annotation reuseIdentifier:identifier];
        } else {
            annotationView.annotation = annotation;
        }

        annotationView.enabled = YES;
        annotationView.canShowCallout = YES;
        annotationView.animatesDrop = YES;

        return annotationView;
    }

    return nil;
}

- (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView regionDidChangeAnimated:(BOOL)animated {

    //Get the east and west points on the map so we calculate the distance (zoom level) of the current map view.
    MKMapRect mRect = self.mapView.visibleMapRect;
    MKMapPoint eastMapPoint = MKMapPointMake(MKMapRectGetMinX(mRect), MKMapRectGetMidY(mRect));
    MKMapPoint westMapPoint = MKMapPointMake(MKMapRectGetMaxX(mRect), MKMapRectGetMidY(mRect));

    //Set our current distance instance variable.
    currenDist = MKMetersBetweenMapPoints(eastMapPoint, westMapPoint);

    //Set our current centre point on the map instance variable.
    currentCentre = self.mapView.centerCoordinate;

}
```

Comment: The code in didAddAnnotationViews and regionDidChangeAnimated doesn't make sense.  If you want to get the places after the map view knows the user's location, call queryGooglePlaces in the didUpdateUserLocation delegate method (but check that 1. The userLocation is valid/accurate, 2. You haven't already called queryGooglePlaces).

Answer (score 0):

call  **- (IBAction)showPlace:(id)sender**  this method using **perform selector** once you  have fetched all the data.

Comment: but I'm already calling fetchedData on the main thread. How exactly would that look?...

Comment: you  are calling fetch  data on main thread. its  ok. but in fetch data at the end when all data are fetched you  need to add                                      [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(showPlace:) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:YES];

Comment: i put that line of code after [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(fetchedData:) withObject:data waitUntilDone:YES]; and nothing happened...weird

Comment: you need to  add this line [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(showPlace:) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:YES];

Comment: yes i added that line you just posted after my previous one. Am i replacing it with the line you just posted?

Answer (score 0):

Use MKMapViewDelegate to know when the user has been found:

```
- (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView didUpdateUserLocation:(MKUserLocation *)userLocation
{
    NSString *lowerString = [tappedString lowercaseString];
    [self queryGooglePlaces:lowerString];
}
```

[MKMapViewDelegate reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/MapKit/Reference/MKMapViewDelegate_Protocol/MKMapViewDelegate/MKMapViewDelegate.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/MKMapViewDelegate/mapView:didUpdateUserLocation:)

Answer (score 0):

You should nest the `dispatch_sync` block inside `dispatch_async` block. Try like this:

```
dispatch_async(kBgQueue, ^{
        NSData* data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL: googleRequestURL];
        dispatch_sync(kBgQueue, ^{
             [self fetchedData:data];
        })
});
```